# HttpParams set null for call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a problem with HttpParams and HttpHeaders after migrating my project from Angular 7 to Angular 8. When I call the API the params are not added. If anyone can help me fix this problem it will be great.

Here is the method in which I define the headers as well as the params.

```js
fetchJson(url: string, parameters ? : any) {
    this.token = this.cookieService.get('access_token');
    this.contrat_token = this.cookieService.get('contrat_token');

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
    headers = headers.append('contrat_token', this.contrat_token);

    let params = new HttpParams()
    params.set('search', parameters);
    console.log('les headers');
    console.log(headers);
    console.log('params');
    console.log(params.toString())

    return this._http.get(url, {
        headers,
        params
      }).pipe(map((resp: any) => {
            if (resp.status === 401 || resp.status == 401 || resp.status.toString() == "401") {
              this.clearCookie();
            } else {
              let reponse = resp;

              if (reponse == -1 || reponse == "-1") {
                this.router.navigate(["/"]);
              }
            }

            return resp;
          }
```

And I call this method in my services as follows.

```js
   getDetailThematiquePrevNext(id: string, typeBase: string) {
        let URL = this.urlDecorator.urlAPIDecorate("DI", "GetDetailThematiqueHeaderPrevNext");
        let params = this.urlDecorator.generateParameters({
            id: id,
            typeBase: typeBase,
          
        });
        return this.apiFetcher.fetchJson(URL, params);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably due to lazy parsing. You have to do a `get` or `getAll` to access values to determine the state.

> HttpParams class represents serialized parameters, per the MIME type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. **The class is immutable** and all mutation operations return a new instance.
>
> HttpHeaders class represents the header configuration options for an HTTP request. Instances should be assumed **immutable with lazy parsing**.

You may want to pass your options directly into the instance for both headers and params:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token,
  'contrat_token': this.contrat_token
});

let params = new HttpParams({
  search: parameters
});
```

As @Siraj stated in an answer, there are alternative ways to set values for headers and params such as [`set`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#set)...

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('name', 'value');
let params = new HttpParams().set('name', 'value');
```

Or [`append`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#append)...

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders().append('name', 'value');
let params = new HttpParams().append('name', 'value');
```

The important thing to note here is that these methods require chaining otherwise each method creates a new instance.

You could also convert objects like so:

```
let headerOptions = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token,
  'contrat_token': this.contrat_token
}

let headers = new HttpHeaders();

Object.keys(headerOptions).forEach((key) => {
  headers = headers.set(key, headerOptions[key]);
});
```

It's also worth avoiding any binding of objects by reference, and instead pass as parameters:

```
return this._http.get(url, {
  headers: headers,
  params: params
});
```

And finally, because your type annotation is "any" for the parameters argument, `params` expects HttpParamsOptions which is a key/value object where values must be a string annotation.

```
let params = new HttpParams({
  search: JSON.stringify(parameters)
});
```

Try `console.log(params.getAll('search'))` but, to make sure headers and params are sent, a better place to check will be Network tab in DevTools.

Comment: thant's Cue , I'll  test it and tell you.

Comment: Hi Cue I am tested everything is ok thank's, except that part of params I have an error on it. {search: any} is not assignable to parameters of type HttpParamsOptions.

Comment: You'll want `params: JSON.stringify(parameters)`

Comment: Hi Cue I have test all this but params are always undefined .

Answer (score 1):

Reason provided by Cue is correct, You need to use chaining or do what you did for headers

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token);
headers = headers.append('contrat_token', this.contrat_token);

let params = new HttpParams()
params = params = params.set('search', parameters);
```

More readable way to write this would be as follows

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    .append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token)
    .append('contrat_token', this.contrat_token);

const params = new HttpParams().set('search', parameters);
```

Also, you can drop `Content-Type` header, as it is json by default